# Why does it take much more time to copy complex data

Tags: matlab, time-complexity, complex-numbers

I have a question regarding the processing time of copying data into another array. I noticed that it takes much more time to copy complex single data compared to normal single value. Even if I preallocate both arrays.

```
% Example to show different processing speed of copying data 
T1=0; % total time for single 
T2=0; % total time for complex single 
% preallocate rrays
Csingle = single(zeros(500,3000));
Cimagsingle =complex(Csingle);
for i=1:1000;
    A =rand(500,3000,'single');
    B = 1i.*A;
    tic ;
    C = A;
    t1=toc;
    T1=T1+t1;
    tic;
    Cimag = B;
    t2=toc ;
    T2=T2+t2;
end
```

The processing time in this example is

```
T1 = 0.6105
```

and

```
T2 = 1.1430
```

which is approximatley twice as slow!?

I do not understand this behavior. In a program I am writing to acquire real time data I need to copy complex data into a new array but the processing speed is way to slow. As a result my program is not able to function in real time.

Comment: You mean that for a number defined as having 2 components (a+bi), stuff take twice the time as for a number defined as 1 component (a). Hummmmmm not sure why this surprises you. It is literally double the amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complex number is defined as `a+bi`, as opposed to a real number `a`. This means that for every complex number *two* real numbers are stored. Hence when copying an array of size `x`, it'll take twice as long for the array containing complex numbers as opposed to real numbers.

The same 2 fold difference shows up when using `real(double)` and `real(single)`, as `double` is, as the name suggests, double the size of a `single` variable.

*It's not exactly a two fold difference in time, as there's some overhead of the `tic/toc` functions, initial copying step etc.*

---

Just as a note, using `i` as a loop variable is [generally already frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab), and it's even worse when you're using a complex loop. Simply use `ii` or `k` or `idx` or something as loop variable, not `i`, **especially when using complex numbers**.